# Toast not getting shown

Tags: android, toast

i want to show a toast message, But somehow it is not getting called, below is my oncreate Code.

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.alarm);

            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.raw.alarmclock);
            mediaPlayer.start();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm time up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must call show() after using makeText() to display your message:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm time up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: oh ok, i knew it still missed it. Thanks Sam.

Comment: Although it helped me, I can not vote up or accept your answer, I don't know it is telling i don't have enough reputation to accept or up vote answer, Strange!!

Comment: It should say you must wait 15 minutes before choosing an answer, so try again in 8 minutes. As for reputation to upvote, you'll get there if you answer a few questions. Glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks, New to SO, Will surely do needful

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

```
Toast.makeText(your_activity.this, "u clicked me", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

A known mistake...
You forgot to add the show() method.
Should be

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm time up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```